# Why does sigmoid saturation prevent signal flow through the neuron?

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation, weights, sigmoid, vanishing-gradient-problem

As per [these slides on page 35](http://cse.iitkgp.ac.in/%7Esudeshna/courses/DL17/Backprop-19-Jan-17(1).pdf):

> Sigmoids saturate and kill gradients.
>
> when the neuron's activation saturates at either tail of 0 or 1, the gradient at these regions is almost zero.
>
> the gradient and almost no signal will flow through the neuron to
> its weights and recursively to its data.

So, if the gradient is close to zero, then the error correction would be very minimal. **But why would that cause that no signal flow through the neuron?**

$$w(n+1) = w(n) - \text{gradient}$$

That would only cause the weights not to change.

Comment: I think they mean no signal will flow through the backpropagation since one node close to zero leads to turn off all the gradient of the previous nodes.